# How can I make variables accessible to all the functions within the class in php

Tags: php, oop

I want my variables to be accessible to all the functions within the class in php.
I am giving a sample code of what Im trying to achieve. Please help me out.

```
class ClassName extends AnotherClass {

    function __construct(argument)
    {

    }

    $name = $this->getName();
    $city = $this->getCity();
    $age = 24;


    public function getName() {
        return 'foo';
    }

    public function getCity() {
        return 'kolkata';
    }

    public function fun1() {
        echo $name;
        echo $city;
        echo $age;
    }

    public function fun2() {
        echo $name;
        echo $city;
        echo $age;
    }

    public function fun3() {
        echo $name;
        echo $city;
        echo $age;
    }
}
```

Or if there is any other way to have least overhead .Please suggest

Comment: I'd suggest doing some reading up on classes OOP... And some other peoples examples.... That might set the light bulb off... rather than just giving you the answer...

Comment: @AmitGupta  in the class... no globals

Comment: yes sir I have searched extensively couldn't found any.there where some examples which took use of constructor and then I have to call the variable using $this->var; but i want to call the variable directly $var; @TimBrownlaw

Comment: all are oops based framework. actually Im using codeigniter. @B001

Comment: Hmmm, so the fact that you HAVE to use $this->var versus - you have this idea in your head that you Dont Want too... Leaves me speechless... Good luck with that then...

Comment: @lagbox ohh.. Sorry for my mistake.. We can access like $this->name?

Comment: @AmitGupta yes friend :)

Comment: @lagbox thanks friend :)

Comment: i meant to say we can use OOP approach in those framework and Im new to programming. Correct me if Im wrong sir @B001

Comment: There are tons of OOP based frameworks.... Your request doesn't have to do with any of those but with OOP...

Comment: I guess It cant be done.I was looking for something like static variable concept in java. @TimBrownlaw

Comment: Well you can but you are going to have to do some reading... There are lots of answers on here already to your question... Read Try and Learn...

Answer (score 2):

You can acheave you goal like this :

```
class ClassName extends AnotherClass {

    private $name;
    private $city;
    private $age;

    function __construct(argument)
    {
        $this->name = $this->getName();
        $this->city = $this->getCity();
        $this->age = 24;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return 'foo';
    }
    public function getCity(){
        return 'kolkata';
    }

    public function fun1(){
        echo $this->name; 
        echo $this->city;
        echo $this->age;
    }
    public function fun2(){
        echo $this->name;
        echo $this->city;
        echo $this->age;
    }
    public function fun3(){
        echo $this->name;
        echo $this->city;
        echo $this->age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ClassName extends AnotherClass
{
    protected $name;
    protected $city;
    protected $age = 24;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = $this->getName();
        $this->city = $this->getCity();
    }

    ...

    public function fun1()
    {
        echo $this->name;
        echo $this->city;
        echo $this->age;
    }
    ...
}
```

That would get you going a bit.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set your variables as class attributes:

```
class ClassName extends AnotherClass {
    private $name;
    private $city;
    private $age;

    //Here we do our setters and getters
    public function setName($name)
    {$this->name = $name;}
    public function getName()
    {return $this->name;}

   // you call the setters in your construct, and you set the values there
```

Of course you can set them as private, public or protected, depends if you want them to be accessible only from this class or others.

Comment: did you try this at all? this isn't valid PHP

Comment: still completely INVALID PHP